# Cocoapods - framework not found FirebaseCoreDiagnostics

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, cocoapods

I recently updated to the most recent version of firebase so that I could integrate apple sign in for my ios app (obj-c) and I can't for the life of me work out why I'm getting this error:

ld: framework not found FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Here's my podfile:

```
    platform :ios, '13.7'
    
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 5.0'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 5.2'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 5.2'
    pod 'FBSDKPlacesKit', '~> 5.2'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 5.2'
    pod 'FBSDKMarketingKit'
    
    target 'WriteAnythingPrototype' do
    
    end
```

I've checked my Pods and can see that FirebaseCoreAnalytics is there. Also if I try and manually add the framework into the frameworks folder, I get the error that the framework is duplicated.

I've also tried deleting my derived data and deleting my pod folder and then reinstalling the pods.

I'm at my wits end and can't seem to find this problem online, can anyone please explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something about the Xcode project is corrupt. Try the following:

- `pod deintegrate`
- Examine the resulting xcproject source and remove any FirebaseCoreDiagnostic references.
- Rerun `pod install`

Comment: Thanks Paul, I’ll give that a shot later tonight. I did try a deintegrate but didn’t check to see if there were any references or instances of the framework. Hopefully this will work :(

Comment: Thank you, found a reference that was still active and removed it. It's working now!

Answer (score 14):

I had to remove the framework in "Other linked flags" in target's build settings : look for **OTHER_LDFLAGS** in build settings search bar and remove FirebaseCoreDiagnostics from the list.

Comment: Why is this framework being added to the Other linked flags anyway?

Comment: Thanks... had to do the same for a Google Framework :)

Answer (score 9):

I had same issue with a couple of firebase dependencise I tried `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install` a couple of times nothing worked. But what worked is removing the references from the `.xcodeproj` from the `project.pbxproj` file.

Check screen shot below.[image]

Comment: this helped me to solve "framework not found" issue after flutter libs upgrade. thx!

Comment: thanks very helpfully for Framework not found 'permission_handler, google_maps_flutter, FirebaseCoreDiagnostics'

Comment: They are key values You should delete both the FirebaseCoreDiagnostic and its key.
It worked for me. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Put the pods inside the target, so that they get linked to your target.

```
platform :ios, '13.7'

target 'WriteAnythingPrototype' do
   pod 'Firebase/Database'
   pod 'Firebase/Auth'
   pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
   pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
   pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
   pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
   pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 5.0'
   pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 5.2'
   pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 5.2'
   pod 'FBSDKPlacesKit', '~> 5.2'
   pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 5.2'
   pod 'FBSDKMarketingKit'
end
```

You can find the CocoaPods documentation [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I've done as above but it still didn't fix the error. It just localised the scope of my pod installation (took it out of test and ui test setups which I don't use anyway)

Comment: Try clean build.

Comment: I've done that, also cleared derived data manually, reinstalled pods etc

Comment: Then this might be due to Swift version. Do check theirs versions.

Comment: I'm using objective c though... And do you mean I need to update xcode or?

Comment: I hope you are opening the `.xcworkspace` file, are you?

Comment: Definitely opening .xcworkspace. The app was working fine until I had to update firebase :(