# Shared_preferences on iOS throws PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

Tags: ios, flutter

I have seen multiple posts with this same error, but most seem to be related to Firebase.  This is in a super simple app - no Firebase, no network, it's literally a calculator for a specific kind of problem.  It runs fine on Android, but fails on iOS.

Pubspec.yaml dependencies:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.6 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.1
  async: ^2.11.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.3

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

The only two libs I've added are shared_preferences (to store settings), and async (for FutureGroup).

main.dart (main function)

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPrefs().init().then((void _) {
    SpecificModel.load();
    runApp(MyApp());
  });
}
```

The error occurs on the SharedPrefs().init() line (and I did have the main as async with an await instead of the .then, but changed to .then in desperation while trying *anything* :).

Flutter cli:

```
$ flutter run -d B9B5C8EE-0597-4780-8AB9-86F778472008
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             520ms
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                      2,825ms
Xcode build done.                                           17.5s
[VERBOSE-2:FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(35)] Using the Impeller rendering backend.
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
Syncing files to device iPhone 14 Pro...                            76ms
```

`flutter doctor` says everything is fine, and `flutter pub outdated` says that everything is up to date, both direct and indirect dependencies.

I have done the whole sequence of `flutter clean`, `rm -rf ios/Pods`, `rm podFile.lock`, `flutter pub get` multiple times.

The only thing that almost worked was to do a new flutter project, copy the existing code in, and then it worked.  For a little while, then this came back.  So pretty sure it isn't the code, but the environment.

Other things that I have tried - clearing the pod cache, deintegrating, rebuilding the flutter cache, and then doing a pod install (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72282180/682938) answer), same result.

Running in Xcode directly is interesting, it flat out won't link, saying `Framework not found shared_preferences_foundation`.  Building from the flutter command works fine, though.

```
flutter build ios
Changing current working directory to: /Users/blahblah/project
Building com.company.project for device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: ##########
Running pod install...                                             512ms
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         4.2s
Xcode build done.                                           32.9s
Built /Users/blahblah/project/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app.
```

The only step I have left is to go through the whole "create a blank project and fill in the code" process and try to track where things go wrong.

Requested Edit - pubspec.lock section for shared_preferences

```
  shared_preferences:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: shared_preferences
      sha256: b7f41bad7e521d205998772545de63ff4e6c97714775902c199353f8bf1511ac
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.2.1"
  shared_preferences_android:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: shared_preferences_android
      sha256: fe8401ec5b6dcd739a0fe9588802069e608c3fdbfd3c3c93e546cf2f90438076
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.2.0"
  shared_preferences_foundation:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: shared_preferences_foundation
      sha256: d29753996d8eb8f7619a1f13df6ce65e34bc107bef6330739ed76f18b22310ef
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.3.3"
  shared_preferences_linux:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: shared_preferences_linux
      sha256: "71d6806d1449b0a9d4e85e0c7a917771e672a3d5dc61149cc9fac871115018e1"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.3.0"
  shared_preferences_platform_interface:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: shared_preferences_platform_interface
      sha256: "23b052f17a25b90ff2b61aad4cc962154da76fb62848a9ce088efe30d7c50ab1"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.3.0"
  shared_preferences_web:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: shared_preferences_web
      sha256: "7347b194fb0bbeb4058e6a4e87ee70350b6b2b90f8ac5f8bd5b3a01548f6d33a"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.2.0"
  shared_preferences_windows:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: shared_preferences_windows
      sha256: f95e6a43162bce43c9c3405f3eb6f39e5b5d11f65fab19196cf8225e2777624d
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.3.0"
```

Requested Edit - podFile.lock

```
PODS:
  - Flutter (1.0.0)
  - shared_preferences_foundation (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
    - FlutterMacOS

DEPENDENCIES:
  - Flutter (from `Flutter`)
  - shared_preferences_foundation (from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_foundation/darwin`)

EXTERNAL SOURCES:
  Flutter:
    :path: Flutter
  shared_preferences_foundation:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_foundation/darwin"

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  Flutter: f04841e97a9d0b0a8025694d0796dd46242b2854
  shared_preferences_foundation: 5b919d13b803cadd15ed2dc053125c68730e5126

PODFILE CHECKSUM: 6b9eb94e9f98a329f2ef624b852a6e42d090af2b

COCOAPODS: 1.12.1
```

Contents of the :path: folder:

```
~/Documents/repo/personal/project_bad/ios/.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_foundation/darwin
$ ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  4 gbryant  staff   128 Aug 15 12:29 Classes
drwxr-xr-x  3 gbryant  staff    96 Aug 15 12:29 Tests
-rw-r--r--  1 gbryant  staff  1269 Aug 15 12:29 shared_preferences_foundation.podspec
```

Call stack is simply main->SharedPrefs.init:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what it's going on without the entire stacktrace and details of `SharedPrefs` and `SpecificModel`. But I recommend to create shared preferences using `getInstance` constructor` as [documentation says](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences).

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  preferences.setInt("counter", 10);

  final counter = preferences.getInt("counter");
  debugPrint("Counter $counter");

  runApp(const MainApp());
}
```

Other thing that could help us to understand more the problem is share the part of `pubspec.lock` and `Podfile.lock` to see if `shared_preferences_foundation` is there.

Comment: getInstance is actually what the SharedPrefs wrapper does, identical code to what I use in other projects.  Added the requested files.